# What does it mean when we combine text features and feed it to a Neural Network?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am reading this paper -["Review Spam Detection Using Word Embeddings and Deep Neural Networks" - paywall link](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-19823-7_28) and here they talk about how they combined ngram and skip-gram features of text before feeding it to the to feed-forward network.Here is the architecture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcIiV.png)

Some brief description of the dataset:-

- no. of documents=1600
- dimension of skip-gram model=500
- no. of the n-gram features(uni,bi,trigram)=2000

For example:-The pictures show that skip-gram and n-gram models were combined before they were sent as an input to the feed-forward network.
Let's suppose the dimension of skip-gram is (no. of documents, dimension of skip-gram) and the dimension of the n-gram model is (no. of documents, no. of n-gram features)
My question is what does it mean when you combine two different features like skip-gram and n-gram. Does it mean concatenation i.e how do you combine two features? Along which axis do you combine those features?

> The size of the word vectors (embeddings) was set to 500 and context size c = 5 [7]
> to generate a complex representation. The average values of the vector were used to
> represent each review. Thus, the input attributes (features) for the subsequent supervised
> learning included 2000 n-grams and 500 embeddings.
> Deep feedforward neural network (DNN) was used to classify reviews into
> spam/legitimate categories.

Hope I have explained it well this time

Comment: It's hard to tell what the paper was doing with the n-grams from just the abstract. (As just one example, are they talking about word-n-grams, or character-n-grams.) Is a free link, such as at arxiv.org, available?

Comment: Not showing in a Sci-Hub title search. It may make sense to email the authors directly, to get their clarification of how they're integrating word-ngrams into the neural-net inputs.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If there is a specific part of the paper which is unclear, it **might** be appropriate to quote that section in your question & ask for clarification of what the domain-specific language means, in terms of programming implementation. But, requiring download of a non-public paper from a 3rd-party site to check if it already has the answer is a bit much to ask.